# Using grepl with paste to match substring of very large dataset

Tags: r

I have a column vector `Item_A` with around 150,000 observations (1 column variable), and another column vector `Item_B` with 650 observations.
If the single-word string in `Item_B` is present in `Item_A`, a column should output `TRUE`.

Using solutions for searching the substring in `Item_B` within `Item_A`, and giving a vector with `TRUE` or `FALSE`, the following code was suggested:

```
  answer <-  grepl(paste(Item_B, collapse = "|"), Item_A)
```

`grepl` in combination with `paste` works, but only if Item_B is a smaller vector. I first tried with only 20 observations in Item_B, and it works perfectly.
Unfortunately, I get the error: `Error in grepl(paste(Item_B, collapse = "|"), Item_A) :` when I try with my `Item_B` vector of 652 observations.

Do you have any suggestions to make it work for large vectors?

This is what I am hoping my output looks like:

```
Item_A          Item_B         Output_X
cri               bat             TRUE
sug               cri             FALSE
cri ird            NA             TRUE
sure bat           NA             TRUE
dev dev            NA             FALSE
batsman            NA             TRUE
```

Comment: That should work... have you tried matching Item_A to each element of Item_B to see if that works? i.e. `sapply(Item_B, grepl, Item_A)`

Comment: it works when Item_B has only a few observations, not 650. I have not tried sapply. Will check and revert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `stringi`, on my simulated example it works almost 50x faster than `grepl`:

```
# sample data
set.seed(47)
a = replicate(150000, sample(letters, size = 6))
b = replicate(600, sample(letters, size = 3))

big_pat = paste(b, collapse = "|")
ans_stringi = stri_detect_regex(a, big_pat)
ans_grepl = grepl(pattern = big_pat, x = a)
identical(ans_stringi, ans_grepl)
# [1] TRUE

# timing comparison
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  stringi = stri_detect_regex(a, big_pat),
  grepl = grepl(pattern = big_pat, x = a),
  times = 10L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  stringi   344.5289   348.7399   404.7191   409.6438   443.1995   477.3867    10
#    grepl 17323.6438 18743.7462 19058.1780 19192.0434 20012.5553 20061.1821    10
```

---

A non-regex alternative is to use `fixed` patterns and do one `grepl` per `b` item. But I found this much slower than the above solution.

```
ans_fixed = apply(sapply(Item_B, grepl, x = Item_A, fixed = TRUE), MAR = 1, FUN = any)
```

Using `fixed = TRUE` will make each `grepl` very fast, but there are still a lot of them, and it creates a large (`length(a)` by `length(b)`) matrix for the results, which could eat up a lot of memory. In my testing, `grepl` was faster than `stri_detect_fixed` here.

If you run into memory problems, do it in chunks, say 100 `Item_B` values at a time.

Comment: ans_fixed = apply(sapply(Item_B, grepl, x = Item_A, fixed = TRUE), MAR = 1, FUN = any) solution definitely works for me. Thank you.

however, for stri_detect_regex, I get the following error: Error in stri_detect_regex(a, big_pat) : 
  could not find function "stri_detect_regex"

I have installed the stringi and stringr packages, but still get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you load `library(stringi)`? Either that or check your spelling. You could also try specifying `stringi::stri_detect_regex`, but that shouldn't make any difference if the package is loaded.